# How to ignore or inspect "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Violation of encoding rules" in PHP

Tags: php, soap

Hi i make a soap call in my php application

```
$options = array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'trace' => 1,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'local_cert' => 'my.key',
);
$client = new SoapClient('http://domain.com/my.wsdl', $options);
var_dump($client->functionName($args));
```

which results in an exception

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Violation of encoding rules
```

i guess the problem is the server-respnse, because

```
$client->__getLastResponse()
```

contains a good-looking server response, according to other questions there is probably a value type mismatch.

Is it possible to find out which value is causing this error or is it possible to disable this check?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: if i remember right, one of the api developers made a correction in their api

Comment: An update with the answer would be gold .. :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably are right and the problem is in the server-response, I had similar problem, the returned XML was well formatted and looked good, but it didn't pass the schema validation.

I don't know how to debug it in PHP and I also would like to know how to ignore this validation (and error throwing) but this answer helped me to find the problem in response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12171635/3999906