# How to make my web service url case insensitive?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, apache-axis

I have generated a web service from an existing wsdl file using Axis2, and now my service is reachable by a url

```
http://something/Service?wsdl
```

The problem is, there are some applications which call this url, adding an upper case word "WSDL" at the end of url (please don't ask why..), so they are calling it as,

```
http://something/Service?WSDL
```

And they can't access it at that url.
Is it possible to solve this problem? Maybe setting some parameter or making this url case insensitive someway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a quick look at the Axis2 code and it seems the `?wsdl` extension compare is case sensitive. [This thing sometimes happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961892/any-difference-between-a-wsdl-and-wsdl-parameter/24973088#24973088).

You could have a look at the code yourself and see if there is some switch somewhere to make this case insensitive (in case I missed something when looking at the code).

What you could do is have a filter in your application that looks at the query string and if it finds `?WSDL` in there, in any case whatsoever, to do a redirect to the same URL but with a lower case `?wsdl`. This of course assumes that the clients that try to access the WSDL can follow redirects.

> The problem is, there are some applications which call this url, adding an upper case word "WSDL" at the end of url (please don't ask why..)

Sorry, but why? The most simple way is to tell clients to use a lower case parameter instead of an upper case one. If they can do a call with `?WSDL` why is it so hard to do one with `?wsdl`?

Comment: Client applications can't change anything in their behaviour, there was an old web service (developed in .NET) that I have to replace with a new one developed in Java, and this must be transparent for the clients. There were no problems with case sensitivity in the old service. Anyway, I did it with a servlet filter and a redirect to the same url with a lower "?wsdl", as you said.