# PHP XML Soap Request - [env:Server ] Invalid Credentials

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I am trying to create an XML SOAP request to a WSDK service via PHP - my code is as follows:

```
<?php

        //WSSE Authentication Header Object
class WsseAuthHeader extends SoapHeader {

    private $wss_ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';

    function __construct($user, $pass, $ns = null) {
        if ($ns) {
            $this->wss_ns = $ns;
        }

        $auth = new stdClass();
        $auth->Username = new SoapVar($user, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);
        $auth->Password = new SoapVar($pass, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);

        $username_token = new stdClass();
        $username_token->UsernameToken = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns);

        $security_sv = new SoapVar(
                new SoapVar($username_token, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'Security', $this->wss_ns);
        parent::__construct($this->wss_ns, 'Security', $security_sv, true);
    }

}

//Set WSSE Variables
$username = 'username';
$password = 'pw';
$wsdl = 'wsdlurl';

$wsse_header = new WsseAuthHeader($username, $password);

//Create Soap Client
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,array("trace" => 1));

//Set SOAP headers
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($wsse_header));


$xml_text =  "<v1:MembershipNumber>999999</v1:MembershipNumber>";

$v1 = new SoapVar($xml_text, 147);



//Create Object
$request = array(
        "MembershipNumber"  => $v1,
);

var_dump($request);

//$results = $client->GetMemberNumber($request);
$results = $client->__soapCall('GetMemberNumber', array('MemberNumberRequest'=>$request));
//Print Results
echo "<br /><br />REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "<br /><br />";
echo "REQUEST HEADERS:\n" . $client->__getLastRequestHeaders() . "<br /><br />";
echo "RESPONSE:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "<br /><br />";
echo "RESPONSE HEADERS:\n" . $client->__getLastResponseHeaders() . "<br /><br />";
echo "Var Dump: "; var_dump($results);

?>
```

The XML Request should be in the following format:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="schemaurl">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:MemberNumberRequest>
         <v1:MemberNumber>?</v1:MemberNumber>
      </v1:MemberNumberRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

At the moment I am getting the error:

"Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [env:Server ] Invalid Credentials"

- If I use a regular array instead of the SoapVar's I do not get the credentials error - my username and password are definitely correct.

How do I get the request into the correct XML request format using PHP?

Comment: The error message signals invalid credentials, so most likely the WsseAuthHeader doesn't ship the correct credentials *or* has a problem encoding them (or both). Where did you copy the **WsseAuthHeader** code from? Has it been reported working there? Is this constantly tested automatically?

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end the problem ended up being at the service end, I was not provided the correct set of test data. |
So the credentials and the call was correct.

Comment: Although for anyone who stumbles upon this - the developers changed something on the service-

Originally this worked:
`//Set SOAP headers
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($wsse_header));
$results = $client->__soapCall('FunctionName', array('FunctionRequest'=>$request));`

Then I had to change it to:
`$results = $client->__soapCall('FunctionName', array('FunctionRequest'=>$request), null, array($wsse_header))`

Finally I had to go back to the first option to get it to work, I'm not sure what changed.

Comment: You can leave your solution as an answer below and mark it as the answer. This will make visible what your solution was and that it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the end my code was okay but I was still having problems.

Final solution was to clear WSDL cache:
[In PHP how can you clear a WSDL cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303488/in-php-how-can-you-clear-a-wsdl-cache)

I used both methods to clear the cache (init and dynamically)

[UPDATE]
Still have problems with the invalid server credentials error every now and then, not sure why. Though clearing cache seemed to work for a little while.