# Laravel 5.8 is not always updating newly written code

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I'm running a Laravel 5.8 project on PHP 7.2 and I use PhpStorm is my editor on Mac OS 10.15.4.

Since recent, when I write new code, most of the time in a Class, my changes do not take effect in the application itself. PhpStorm and other editors show my new or edited code, but nothing changes in my application. The only thing that solves this issue is a full reboot of my computer. Doing a full reboot and starting everything up again takes a lot of time and time is precious.

What I have tried other than a full reboot:

- Restarting PHP
- Restarting Nginx
- Restarting PhpStorm
- Restarting using `valet restart`
- Removing the project and cloning from git repo again
- Clearing my config > `php artisan config:clear`
- Caching my config > `php artisan config:cache`

None of these had any successful results so far.

What could cause this weird bug and is there a way to fix this?
Any help or information regarding this is well-received.

Comment: are you using opcache or something similar ( it should say in `phpinfo()` )? Does restarting the PHP-FPM service help ? (If you're using FPM)

Comment: @apokryfos restarting PHP-FPM does not help. Opcode Caching is Disabled, but phpinfo() shows me SHM Cache is Enabled.

Comment: Also check `opcache` settings in your `php.ini` file, I had a similar issue because of that, try to set it false.

Comment: @endo64 opcache is also disabled in my `php.ini` file. I did some more research and my issue might also be because of  WSDL caching. So I checked that and it was enabled. I disabled it, hopefully this resolves my issue.

Comment: Ok, if it is the case, you can answer & accept your own question for further reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can add code

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
```

or manualy remove all wsdl* files in your /tmp folder on the server.

WSDL files are cached in your default location for all cache files defined in php.ini. Same location as your session files.

[In PHP how can you clear a WSDL cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303488/in-php-how-can-you-clear-a-wsdl-cache)