# Where is the PHP SOAP cache folder on Windows?

Tags: php, soap

Looking at the value of [`soap.wsdl-cache-dir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soap.configuration.php#ini.soap.wsdl-cache-dir) in the output of phpinfo() it says that the files are in `/tmp`.  That's obviously not the case on Windows, so where would I find the SOAP cache?

Comment: See what `phpinfo` says for the tmp dir? Not sure on needs but assume aware of `ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", WSDL_CACHE_NONE);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In PHP how can you clear a WSDL cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303488/in-php-how-can-you-clear-a-wsdl-cache)

Comment: sys_temp_dir has no value.  I've already looked at the other question and that does not actually answer this question

Comment: Confirm this is `WSDL_CACHE_DISK`? https://www.php.net/manual/en/soap.configuration.php

Comment: soap.wsdl_cache is 1, yes

Comment: Try and set an explicit `wsdl_cache_dir`? Also, would like to know if overridden on SoapClient constructor with `cache_wsdl` param. Share some of that code? Oh, and I'd check `sys_get_temp_dir()` where the code runs.

Comment: The question isn't "where is the folder on my system", the question is "where does PHP store it on a Windows installation"

Comment: The answer is it depends. You are not describing your environment adequately enough to really answer. PHP configuration and version, Windows version, etc.  I'm just proposing that by being explicit in your setup you can avoid these environment variabilities. Good luck!